# unable to go into fastboot on LG phone

Tags: bootloader, root-access, adb

I have been told that LG phones are painful to get into fastboot but i didn't realize it was impossible. I have the LG K8 2017 (LG-M200n) and I have tried all: #adb devices shows the device is listed, then #adb reboot bootloader does nothing but reboot my usb connected phone. of course fastboot devices shows nothing. I even tried the recommendations to enter fastboot by power down phone, vol down key and connect usb, but phone turns on normal, no fastboot. any help?

Comment: can you enter any other mode? https://www.hardreset.info/devices/lg/lg-k8-2017-m200n/download-mode

Comment: yes download mode i can enter into it ok. I found the answer please see below. sad.

Comment: check fastboot devices in download mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It is not possible because of the hardware itself. LG sucks really. Here is the info from their developers site which explains all the difficulty (LG K8 not listed below :():

```
"The following devices support unlocking the bootloader:
• LG V50: LMV500EM for the European market 
• LG V40: LMV405EBW for the European market 
• LG G7: LMG710EM for the European market 
• LG V30: H930 and H930G for the European market
• LG G6: US997.USA for the U.S. open market
• LG G6: H870 for the European market
• LG V20: US996.USA for the U.S. open market
• LG V10: H960A for the European market and Android M (Except France)
• LG G5 SE: H840 for the European market
• LG G5: RS988.USA for the U.S. open market
• LG G5: H850 for the European market
• LG G4: H815 for the European market
Unlocking the Bootloader is only supported on selected devices."
```

The lesson learned here: verify the capabilities of the phone you want to buy before wasting your money.

Comment: https://youtu.be/3ExyUX4AC6w

Comment: nope. this is not a verified method. no links or guarantees. plus I am wary when a product is asking for $ without proofs. my answer above is still valid (unfortunately)

Comment: i don't want you to buy $ 399 https://octoplusbox.com it is for professional use only. but it is possible (not for consumers, at least). consider paying ~ 20 bucks for a unlock service, sure you will find someone who can do it